# Simple Alternative to document.write

Tags: javascript

I'm teaching myself JavaScript and I'm a little bit stuck.  Here's what I'm trying to do:  I have an image, and once that image is clicked it disappears and is replaced by two other images.  My code works, but it replaces everything on the page instead of just swapping out the images.  I think that I have to use innerHTML somehow, but when I tried that, none of the images showed up.  My code is below-I'd greatly appreciate any insights or explanations-thank you!

```
<body>
  <h1>JavaScript Image Test</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">

function showImage(){
        document.write(puppy);
   }

var dog = '<div id="dog"><a href="#"><img src="images/dog.jpg" onclick="showImage();"></a></div>';
var puppy = '<div id="puppy"><img src="images/puppy.jpg"><img src="images/puppy2.jpg"></div>';


document.write(dog);


</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you saying you would like to display both `dog.jpg` and `puppy.jpg` when the dog image is clicked?

Comment: It's great that you're teaching yourself.  I highly recommend that for the time, you ignore jQuery.  It's powerful and generally accepted, but will obscure a lot of the basics of JavaScript that you should initially learn.  In this specific instance, most of the syntax that jQuery would give you is already pretty easy to do with pure JavaScript anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Write out the dog div as normal html and then replace it's contents:

```
<body>
  <h1>JavaScript Image Test</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showImage(){
    document.getElementById("dog").innerHTML = puppy;
}

var puppy = '<img src="images/puppy.jpg"><img src="images/puppy2.jpg">';
</script>
<div id="dog"><a href="#"><img src="images/dog.jpg" onclick="showImage();"></a></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into `document.createElement()` or the whole jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery... This will replace `dog.jpg` with `puppy.jpg` when the link is clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function showImage(){  
        $('#dog').attr('src', 'images/puppy.jpg');
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="showImage();"><img id="dog" src="images/dog.jpg" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

for an image swap you can just get the image (give the image you create an Id first) and then say:

```
document.getElementById("PetImg").src("images/puppy2.jpg");
```

To follow with what you're doing you could also take change puppy to do something like:

```
document.getElementById("dog").appendChild(puppy);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner HTML works like this:

```
<body>
<h1>JavaScript Image Test</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">

function showImage(){
  var div = document.getElementById('images');
  div.innerHTML = '<img src="images/dog.jpg" onclick="showImage();">'
} 

</script>

<div id='images'>
  <img src="images/puppy.jpg">
  <img src="images/puppy2.jpg">
</div>

</body>
```

Although there may be better ways of switching the images, if your learning Javascript stay away from jQuery as the other comments may have said its a good idea to learn these fundamentals first.

Comment: I would disagree. I started off learning jQuery and have picked up bits and pieces of Javascript over time. I've found jQuery to be a pleasure to work with and would encourage any beginning programmer to dive in and do the same.

Comment: I'd agree with Mr Jones here. jQuery is fantastic, and considering most people use it already, something one should learn.

Comment: Nothing wrong with learning jQuery but why would you load the whole library for something than can be done so simply with native JavaScript? jQuery is seen as a quick and simple solution rather than writing clean and efficient code.

Comment: The performance hit of loading jQuery is negligible, and in my opinion jQuery allows you to more easily interact with the DOM. Your aversion to using libraries is severely misplaced; most languages provide libraries for a reason - it makes things easier.

Answer (score -1):

You may consider picking up a Javascript framework, jQuery is popular and makes this task relatively easy. Instead of replacing all of the HTML, you can update the `src` attribute on the image. Something like:

```
$('#some_div img').attr('src', 'images/some_image.jpg');
```

Alternatively you can replace the html as well:

```
$('#some_div').html('<img src="images/some_image.jpg" />');
```